# Reconciling Kendo Theme with jQ UI Themes

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo with the "Silver" color palette. I also use jQ UI for certain things but mainly want to re-use the jQ UI sprite for various images. Question: Do the Kendo themes correspond to any of the pre-rolled jQ UI themes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, they use different themes, images, sprites... But you can customize Kendo UI themes using [`KendoUI ThemeBuilder`](http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html)